# HX711 Power Down Handling

Tags: low-power, esp8266

I have hooked my HX711 to an ESP8266. I'm now faced with the problem that once I put my ESP into deep sleep mode the GPIO Pin which is hooked to the PD_SCK pin goes low.

This in turn will put the HX711 in "normal mode".

> When PD_SCK Input is low, chip is in
>   normal working mode. (Page 5)

How can I keep both devices in power down mode?

> When PD_SCK pin changes from low to high and stays at high for longer than 60µs, HX711 enters power down mode.

I tried to pull up the PD_SCK pin and use the ESP8266 gpio pin as a drain but that did not work. Maybe I did something wrong.

I could introduce an inverting 74xx chip but that just seems wrong. Is there maybe something I overlooked?

https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/hx711_english.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a FET to allow Open Drain operation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVzBzw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The [RUM001L02](http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/transistor/mosfet/rum001l02t2cl-e.pdf) has a very low VGS(threshold) and is readily available. Remember your PD_SCK is now logically inverted.

Answer (score 0):

Set the PD_SCK pin to the output mode before readings, and to the HIGH-Z/INPUT mode before esp8266/hx711 powerdown, use pullup resistor.